Can I travel with my valid Trinidad e-visa in my new passport if my old passport was "cancelled without prejudice"?
I need some advice. I recently renewed my passport because I'm going to be out of the country for a while. I got my Trinidad e-visa using the old passport, but when my new one arrived, they "Cancelled without Prejudice" the old one. Does this mean my e-visa for Trinidad is still valid even though it's attached to my canceled passport? I know some countries don't have an issue with this, but I'm unsure about Trinidad and Tobago. I plan to present both passports on arrival.
Has anyone experienced this or know the rules? Thanks!

Related: Valid UK Visa in an Expired Passport. Your passport issuer cannot cancel a visa from another country (and they can't issue you a replacement visa).

@WeatherVane Countries can still choose not to accept visas in cancelled passports.
